# Does each variable in a premises undergoing Universal Instantiation have to change?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I'm currently working on this problem:

> “All movies produced by John Sayles are wonderful. John Sayles produced a movie about coal miners.
>   Therefore, there is a wonderful movie about coal miners.”

My domain/Universe consists of all movies.

- P(x,y): x produced y
- W(x): x is a wonderful movie
- c : a movie about coal miners

Premises 1. $∀x(P (John Sayles, x) → W(x))$

Premises 2. $P(John Sayles, c)$

Therefore 3. $∃xW(c)$

I want to take premises 1 and use Universal Instantiation to get this: $P(John Sayles, c) → W(c))$

I'm not sure if that's an ok thing to do with universal instantiation or if it's wrong.

Comment: Personally, I would make "about coal miners" into another predicate, and then interpret the second condition as an existential statement also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you instantiate you have to instantiate every free variable quantified by the quantifier that you are dropping.

And that is exactly what you do when going from $\forall x (P(JohnSayles,x) \to W(x))$ to $P(JohnSayles,c) \to W(c)$, so what you do here is correct.

What is not correct, however, is your symbolization. Note that your conclusion is really weird: $\exists x W(c)$ has no free variables $x$, so what are you quantifying here?

So, I would use a predicate $C(x)$ that means that '$x$ is a movie about coal miners'. With that, you get:

$\forall x (P(j,x) \to W(x))$

$\exists x (P(j,x) \land C(x))$

$\therefore \exists x (W(x) \land C(x))$

Comment: That's a lot better! Now there's not more than three potential variables within each predicate. I had a feeling like my setup was off a few minutes after I posted this... I'll work on this setup and see where it goes. Also, knowing that instantiation affects free variables only is super helpful!

Comment: @NickSabia right .. but again, when instantiating, you have to replace *every* free variable ... and with the *same* constant.  Good luck and glad I could help! :)